# Temporarily overwrite a macro in C preprocessor

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I need to temporarily overwrite a macro and then restore it. Like:

```
#define FOO X
#save FOO
#define FOO Y
...
#restore FOO
```

Is it possible in standard C preprocessor? In GCC?

**ADDED**. About real world example. I use a global macro for error exception. It acts like `assert`, but for persistent usage, not only for debug versions; so, for example, I usually call functions (with side-effect) inside the macro. It's defined once, but the definition isn't persistent; therefore I don't know it a-priori. For some piece of code I need its own, modified version of the macro, but I want to *save general style of code*. It's looks ugly when one part of code uses the one macro, other part uses other macro -- both macros have the *same purpose*, but slightly different implementation.

So, it's good for me to save original macro temporarily, use different version for a part of code, after that restore original macro.

Comment: Unless you know exactly what `FOO` is before and after, no, this isn't possible.

Comment: Why not just change the names of the macros? Seems a lot simpler.

Comment: No sure about plain C, but in c++ you can use push_macro: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543736/how-do-i-temporarily-disable-a-macro-expansion-in-c-c

Comment: @Ed Heal: How? If you mean `#define FOO_SAVED FOO` and then `#define FOO FOO_SAVED` -- it doesn't work, obviously.

Comment: You do have control over the source code? notepad++ could change those names

Comment: What is actually your use case for this? Can you give a real world example of when this will be useful for you?

Comment: I updated the question for application note. Sorry for bad English please, it's not my native.

Comment: @AlexG.P.: `push_macro` is not standard

Comment: @AlexG.P.: Oh, `push_macro` it's seems to be what I search. GCC support it.

Comment: @K-ballo: I have asked about GCC extensions too.

Comment: @user14284: I know. His comments says _in C++ you can use `push_macro`_, but that's not true; you can only use `push_macro` in _MSVC_ and _GCC_, not in _C++_

Comment: @K-ballo: I know about standard =) Most of #pragra aren't standard, but it is exists and useful for OP. About terminology... We understood each other.

Comment: An instruction like that would be nice to introduce kind-of-a-scope for macros.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I redefine a C++ macro then define it back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793800/can-i-redefine-a-c-macro-then-define-it-back)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As already said, it is not really possible. Depending on the situation, this might be a workaround:

```
#include "generalmacrodefs.h" // put them in here or include them indirectly
#undef macro1
#define macro1 "specialized temporary value"
#undef macro1
#include "generalmacrodefs.h" // restores
```

This requires that `generalmacrodefs.h` uses a pattern like this at least for the definitions you might temporarily overwrite:

```
#ifndef macro1
#define macro1 "original value"
#endif
```

Comment: In both gcc and Visual Studio, you can use #pragma push_macro and #pragma pop_macro.

Answer (score 18):

This is possible with `#pragma push_macro` and `#pragma pop_macro`. These are not standard C—they're originally an MSVC extension—but [clang supports them](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Preprocessor.html#a04dec9fbfa220dfea433bcbeffa270c3), and [so does GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/gcc/Push_002fPop-Macro-Pragmas.html).

Example usage:

```c
int main() {
#define SOME_MACRO 1
  printf("SOME_MACRO = %d\n", SOME_MACRO);
#pragma push_macro("SOME_MACRO")
#define SOME_MACRO 2
  printf("SOME_MACRO = %d\n", SOME_MACRO);
#pragma pop_macro("SOME_MACRO")
  printf("SOME_MACRO = %d\n", SOME_MACRO);
  return 0;
}
```

prints:

```
SOME_MACRO = 1
SOME_MACRO = 2
SOME_MACRO = 1
```

You can also `#undef` a macro inside a `push_macro` / `pop_macro` pair, and the `pop_macro` call will redefine it.

Comment: If the macro did not exist when `push_macro` is called, then `pop_macro` will also undefine it. (at least on MSVC)

Comment: If the macro is defined before the push_macro pragma is used, it is still defined afterwards, so technically you need to undef the macro before redefining it. Nevertheless I pretty much like this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can come in C is the `#undef` directive, which simply undefines the macro, allowing it to be replaced:

```
#define FOO X

...

#undef FOO
#define FOO Y

...

#undef FOO
#define FOO X
```

The problem is that you cannot know the 'old' value of `FOO` once you redefine it - so your values must be hard-coded in one place.

You cannot create a macro to save the values for you either, as it isn't possible to have a macro that creates other preprocessor directives in standard C.

Comment: I don't know old value of `FOO` or it may have too big definition.

Comment: @user14284 then you're plumb out of luck. There is no solution in C for this. Is there any particular reason why you can't re-name the macro?

Comment: Maybe there is solution with GCC? And what you mean in "re-name"?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII - C does not get a looking for macros.