# How to undefine and redefine a macro in C++?

Tags: c++, macros, c++14

I have a macro in the existing part of project that I want to suppress for my includes. The existing macro is defined like this:

```
#define NAME                _T(MYCONST("Name"))
```

However In my library NAME is part of an enum that raise error.

I tried to do it like this:

```
#ifdef MYCONST
#define CONST_DEFINED MYCONST
#undef MYCONST
#endif
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp> ...
#ifdef CONST_DEFINED
#define MYCONSTCONST_DEFINED
#undef CONST_DEFINED
#endif
```

However, in other parts of code that used the MYCONST like `dir += MYCONST("lockapp");`, I have error `E0020 that identifier CONST_DEFINED is undefined`!

Comment: I'm wondering why you are undefining MYCONST not NAME if NAME is the problem

Comment: But really the cause of this problem should be fixed, i.e the stupid macro NAME should be deleted or at the very least renamed to something less likely to clash. Patching rubbish code will probably cost more in the long run,

Comment: Put the `#define BLAH BLAH` in a header file.  `#undef` it when you don't want it.  `#include` that header file when you want it.  And if possible, just don't use macros.  Macros are The Devil™.

Comment: If you use macros at all then avoid macro names that clash. Don't be like MicroSoft that defined macros named min and max in its windows.h and turned lot of standard library hard to use.

Comment: Just rename your macro and move on. Spend your time on something meaningful.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Push_002fPop-Macro-Pragmas.html (Of course, this is a compiler extension. You might be able to reorder your includes so that the conflicting names don't interact with each other, but generally you should namespace your macros too `MYPROJECT_NAME`)

Comment: IMO firs problem is using macro in wrong context. In C++ macros should be avoided as much as possible and should be used as last resort. This `NAME` symbol looks like something what should be a constant or `constexpr`.

Comment: `#define MYCONSTCONST_DEFINED` lacks a space, it should be `#define MYCONST CONST_DEFINED`. As it is, it defines the empty macro named `MYCONSTCONST_DEFINED`.

Comment: Do you have control over code which introduces this `NAME` macro? If yes best approach would be change it to `constexpr auto NAME = _T(MYCONST("Name"));`. Now C++ scope mechanism will resolve problem with `enum` value (unless this is old style enum in global scope).

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the question a written. If you are trying to fix a problem with `NAME` being both a macro and an identifier ("part of an enum"), why does your attempt at fixing undefine `MYCONST`?   Undefining `MYCONST` does not change the fact that `NAME` is defined, and has a name clash.   My suggestion would be to either rename the macro (say to `CONSTNAME`) and leave the enum alone, or change `NAME` to something else in the `enum` and leave the macro alone.  Either way, you'll need to change the code that uses `NAME` accordingly.

Comment: Are you really sure you even NEED macros? `#define NAME                _T(MYCONST("Name"))` should in good C++ be `inline constexpr std::string_view NAME{"Name"};"`

Comment: @PepijnKramer I agree what you suggest is "good C++" but that is not equivalent to what `_T` does.

Comment: I feel like this is almost a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261534/temporarily-overwrite-a-macro-in-c-preprocessor?rq=3

Comment: @Wyck I know, _T conditionally makes it a char* or a wchar_t*, my comment was more on (not) using macros ;)